# Google Maps Marker does not move with search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created a map, and when I search for an address in the input box, my marker does not move to my new location.

I have added this thinking that it will solve my problem, but I guess I do not understand exactly what this snippet is doing

```
  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
```

This is the full HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 #googft-mapCanvas {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here">
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>

<script>

function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
        var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: {
            enabled: false
        },
        query: {
            select: "col26",
            from: "11Q0B7iRayT2JIOBl8_VRUmitimhX1W01byuFDnAv",
            where: ""
        },
        options: {
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2
        }
    });

    if (isMobile) {
        var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
        var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
        var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'block';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
        legendCloseButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'none';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Your New Home",

    });

     // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });


    marker.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.

I deleted some code that wasn't doing anything.  Moving the marker, is this code, at the bottom:  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 #googft-mapCanvas {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here">
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
<script>
function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
        var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: {
            enabled: false
        },
        query: {
            select: "col26",
            from: "11Q0B7iRayT2JIOBl8_VRUmitimhX1W01byuFDnAv",
            where: ""
        },
        options: {
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2
        }
    });
    if (isMobile) {
        var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
        var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
        var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'block';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
        legendCloseButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'none';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Your New Home",
    });
     // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } 
      else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
      // now let's move the marker
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```